# How to get Docker Images from Azure container registry and run onpremise servers using docker-compose?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, docker-compose, azure-pipelines

I am using azure devops for CI/CD pipelines and one thing I couldn't find out, getting images from Azure container registry and run those images inside of my onpremise debian server. (I build and pushed the images to ACR already).

On release pipeline section:

- I set Azure Container repository as source type and selected the latest artifact from there
- then created a dev stage
- Added a Command line tool to execute some scripts on server
- **-->This is the step where I lost<--** I need somehow to get these image from repository and fire compose up command in the server.

Extra info: you cannot use your docker-compose.yml(which mine is inside of the azure repo in same project) because you are using ACR as source type, not the build itself or source code.

*in my humble opinion this is a good case to enrich a content. Because there is lack of docs and videos on internet.

thanks,

Comment: Where you want to deploy your built image ?

Comment: To my debian VM's(on premise) not to azure services machines

Comment: you need to link your VM with the adequate service connection

Comment: Do you mean by deployment groups? like installing azagent to host machines?  If yes, I have that connection